# beamer: How to modify/offset an overlay specification in a custom command?

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

I want a custom command to show some content in slightly different versions in two consecutive overlays. MWE without a custom command:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>
    \only<1>{xA}
    \only<2>{yA}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`\newcommand<>` will give me the full overlay specification as one argument, so there is no chance to modify and reuse it. (Or is there?)

Since I only need a very simple specification to show content on a single page, I use a regular `\newcommand*` and pass the overlay as one parameter. Now, when I try to  modify this parameter the overlay simply gets dropped. No error, but also no content.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\delayDouble}[2]{
    \only<#1>{x#2}
    \only<\numexpr 1+#1\relax>{y#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>
    \delayDouble{1}{A}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces an empty 2nd slide. Interestingly, `\numexpr #1\relax` works fine, but shows both outputs on the same slide, of course.

Why does my approach fail and how can I fix it?

---

As requested, here's more information on the actual use case. I want to embed different pictures in my presentation. In the first step (the overlay given to the command), each should show large in the center of the slide. In subsequent overlays, a small version should appear in its “natural position” on the slide. The code looks like this now

```latex
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\NewDocumentCommand \thumb { D <> {1} +m }
{%
    \only<#1>{%
        \tikz[remember picture, overlay] {%
            \node at (current page) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=.8\textwidth, height=.7\textheight]{#2}};
        }%
    }%
    \visible<+(#1)->{%
        \fbox{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=2cm, height=1cm]{#2}}}%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>
    \thumb<1>{picture.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A simple offset works well for me. I also tried to use Beamer's built-in feature, but in regular `\newcommand` and with the syntax `\only<#1(1)>` it failed.

Comment: Try `\the\numexpr...` instead of just `\numexpr...`

Comment: Do you want to do something more complicated? Because Beamer already lets you specify things like increments.

Comment: @TexMax Can you add some more background information about the use case? I'm wondering if maybe relative overlays would be a simpler approach to your actual problem.

Comment: I thought the result of a `\numexpr` is a number, not a register. Could you enlighten me why `\numexpr #1` works anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulrich Diez already answered your general question in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701963/beamer-how-to-modify-offset-an-overlay-specification-in-a-custom-command#comment1745668_701963), but if you want to do relatively simple transformations such as incrementing relative to the specified overlay specification, then you can just use Beamer's builtin syntax.

This example also uses `\NewDocumentCommand` to support a more Beamer-like syntax.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\NewDocumentCommand \delayDouble { D <> {1} +m }
{%
  \only<#1>{x#2}%
  \only<+(#1)>{X#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>
    \delayDouble<1>{A}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlay-specific output]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the syntax of `\NewDocumentCommand`. The manual gives very little information what the 1st argument does except for saying that it's the overlay specification and `D` provides a default while `d` doesn't. What's the `m` for?

Comment: Never mind. I learned that the command actually comes from [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and is documented there.

Comment: @TexMax If you have a recent installation of TeX, the stuff is now in the LaTeX kernel. Documentation is in `usrguide.pdf`. I get this with e.g. `texdoc usrguide`. `m` is a required argument. `D` is an optional argument with a default which uses non-standard delimiters i.e. not the usual `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make any calculations yourself. Instead you can use beamer's `\temporal` macro:

```
\temporal<overlay specification>{before slide text}{default text}{after slide text}
```

This allows you to specify the content before, on and after the specified overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\newcommand<>{\thumb}[1]{%
  \temporal#2{}{
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] {%
                \node at (current page) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=.8\textwidth, height=.7\textheight]{#1}};
            }%
  }{
    \fbox{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=2cm, height=1cm]{#1}}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>
    \thumb<2>{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]